# How to make a JFrame button open another JFrame class in Textpad

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make an online shop(my assignment). I,m having issue on adding frame. Is there some different way to add frame within a frame in textpad or i,m doing something wrong.Could someone please tell me a way to do this.

Thanks!

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AppStore extends JFrame
{

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 1050;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 550;

    private static final int CANDY_GAME_STOCK = 8;

    private static final int DEFAULT_QUANTITY = 0;
    private static final double DEFAULT_PRICE = 3.5;

    private JLabel candyCrush;
    private JLabel candyStockLabel;
    private JLabel priceLabel;
    private JLabel candyImage;
    private JLabel error;
    private JLabel candyCartLabel;
    private ImageIcon candy;
    private JLabel adding;
    private JButton incCandy;
    private JButton decCandy;
    private JButton buy;
    private JButton addTo;
    private JButton proceed;
    private JTextField quantity;
    private JTextField candyStockField;
    private static JPanel cartPanel;


    private double price;
    private int candyStock;
    private int candyGame;
    private double sum;

    public AppStore()
    {

        price = DEFAULT_PRICE;

        candyStock = CANDY_GAME_STOCK;

        priceLabel = new JLabel("Price: ");
        candyCrush = new JLabel("Candy-Crush Game: ");
        candyStockLabel = new JLabel("In stock: ");
        candyCartLabel = new JLabel("Dear Customer! ");
        error = new JLabel(" ");
        adding = new JLabel("Add this item to shopping cart");

        ImageIcon candy = new ImageIcon("candycrush.jpg");
        candyImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("candycrush.jpg"));
        candyImage = new JLabel(candy);

        createTextField();
        createButton();
        createPanel();
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);


    }

    private void createTextField()
    {

        final int FIELD_WIDTH = 4;
        final int STOCK_WIDTH = 2;
        quantity = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
        quantity.setText("" + DEFAULT_QUANTITY);
        candyStockField = new JTextField(STOCK_WIDTH);
        candyStockField.setText("" + CANDY_GAME_STOCK);
    }

    class IncrementCandy implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            int addition = 1;
            candyGame = candyGame + addition;
            quantity.setText("" + candyGame);

            int newQuantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText());
            double newPrice  = price * newQuantity;
            priceLabel.setText("Price: " + newPrice);
        }
    }

    class DecrementCandy implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            int subtraction = 1;
            candyGame = candyGame - subtraction;
            quantity.setText("" + candyGame);

            int newQuantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText());
            double newPrice  = price * newQuantity;
            priceLabel.setText("Price: " + newPrice);
        }
    }

    class AddToCartListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            int newQuantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText());
            if((newQuantity > 0)&&(newQuantity <= CANDY_GAME_STOCK))
            {
                int remainingStock = CANDY_GAME_STOCK - newQuantity;
                candyStockField.setText("" + remainingStock);
                error.setVisible(false);


            }

            if((newQuantity > CANDY_GAME_STOCK)||(newQuantity <= 0))
            {
                error.setText("Invalid, Selection");
                error.setVisible(true);
            }

        }

    }

    class CartDisplay implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            JFrame shoppingCart = new JFrame();

            int newQuantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText());
            candyCartLabel.setText("Dear Customer! you added " + newQuantity);
            cartPanel.add(candyCartLabel);
            add(cartPanel);
            shoppingCart.setVisible(true);
        }
    }



    private void createButton()
    {
        buy =  new JButton("Buy");


        incCandy = new JButton("+");
        ActionListener listener = new IncrementCandy();
        incCandy.addActionListener(listener);

        decCandy = new JButton("-");
        ActionListener listener2 = new DecrementCandy();
        decCandy.addActionListener(listener2);

        addTo = new JButton("Add to Cart");
        ActionListener stockReduction = new AddToCartListener();
        addTo.addActionListener(stockReduction);

        proceed = new JButton("Proceed");
        ActionListener display = new CartDisplay();
        proceed.addActionListener(display);





    }

    private void createPanel()
    {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        panel.add(candyImage);
        panel.add(candyCrush);
        panel.add(quantity);
        panel.add(candyStockLabel);
        panel.add(candyStockField);
        panel.add(incCandy);
        panel.add(decCandy);
        panel.add(priceLabel);
        panel.add(addTo);
        panel.add(proceed);
        panel.add(error);
        panel.add(adding);
        adding.setOpaque(true);
        adding.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(panel);


    }



    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        AppStore frame = new AppStore();
        frame.setTitle("Appstore");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }



}
```

Comment: *"Is there some different way to add frame within a frame in textpad.."* What do you mean by 'textpad'? The word is only mentioned once in the title and once in the quoted sentence, while the class name is `AppStore`. Is textpad an app. installed on your system? An IDE or text editor you write the code with? Something else? Please explain..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed to init cartPanel before use it, init it in AppStore Constructor.
and before use setVisible(true) for your inner frame you should set the Size for it.
also take a look on JInternalFrame (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html )